# Google Reflections object doesn't instance

Tags: java, reflections

I'm trying to make a class that calls certain instances of an object according to the value of my custom annotation, to it found that, Google Reflection is a good option but I can not instantiate it, what am I doing wrong?

I try

```
public class TesteDeAnotacoes {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {             
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("testedeanotacoes.test");
    }
}
```

and have the follow error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate
    at testedeanotacoes.TesteDeAnotacoes.main(TesteDeAnotacoes.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Predicate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

my project

[image: project view]

I missed some detail for it is not working?

Comment: just add the library to your netbeans project

Comment: ok, I had added but apparently failed in execution, thanks

Comment: could you please elaborate what do you mean by failed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly a dependencies issues, and it is orthogonal to any library.

The best solution is to use a decent build system, and get the transitive dependencies easily. 
Make sure to get familiar with Maven (or Gradle, SBT, ...), and take a look at the pom.xml, especially the dependencies section.

Other solution is to manually download the libraries needed and build the classpath (java -cp ...), or, if available, get a fat-jar which embeds all the dependencies.

Comment: @zapp why use that jar? it didn't make any difference for me.